# How to get next element in a sparse array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm aware that arrays in JavaScript differ from your traditional arrays in the sense that they are just objects under the hood. Because of this, JavaScript allows for sparse arrays to behave in a similar manner to dense arrays when it comes to memory management. When working with a sparse array, is there a way to reach the next element in that array efficiently?

For example, given this array:

```
var foo = [];
foo[0] = '0';
foo[1] = '1';
foo[2] = '2';
foo[100] = '100';

console.log(foo.length); // => 101
```

I'm know that there's a way to get **all** of the elements by using `for ... in` like so:

```
for (var n in foo){
    console.log(n);
}
// Output: 
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 100
```

However, is there an explicit way to simply get from one of these elements to the next?

For example, does there exist some way to achieve similar behavior to this?

```
var curElement = foo[2]; // => 2 (the contents of foo[2])
var nextElement = curElement.next(); // => 100 (the contents of foo[100])
//                           ^^^^^^
// Not an actual function, but does there exist some way to potentially
// mimic this type of behavior efficiently?
```

Comment: No, you'd have to write your own code to do that.

Comment: @Pointy Does there exist an efficient way to do this? The only way I can think of is to iterate through the entire array, ignoring `undefined` values. Surely there must be some more efficient way?

Comment: [Linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) [Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) ?

Comment: @LJᛃ I was considering having a doubly linked list which keeps track of the array's keys, so when `next` is called on an element, it will find the next key in the list and return the element with that key. However this will increase the space by `O(n)` and was wondering if there was some perhaps native way to achieve this behavior, avoiding the additional space complexity.

Comment: Afaik big O is used to refer to *time* complexity which will remain the same. My suggestion aimed at ditching the array and using a linked or doubly linked list exclusively

Comment: @LJᛃ `Big O Notation` can refer to `time` as well as `space` complexities.

Comment: Ok I see. My point still stands though, using a linked list instead of arrays is probably the cleanest and fastest solution.

Comment: @LJᛃ: You should post an answer. I agree that a linked list would make more sense unless there's some need to also share the data as an actual Array elsewhere in code. If that's not the case, I'd push for your answer to be the accepted one.

Comment: @squint I think there is still information missing to provide the "best" answer here as the OPs use case is not quite clear to me. Is the data structure to be iterated sequentially only, are keys to be always numeric, does iteration order matter, whats the ratio between singular random access/iteration/insertion/deletion, are keys to be declared in order, what is more critical space or time complexity, and the list goes on.

Comment: @LJᛃ: No one is expected to write a paper on the absolute best possible solution for the Nick Zuber problem. Given his requirements in the question, a linked list seems like a good possibility and probably better, or at least simpler, than my `SparseArray` type below. Certainly going from the currently held item to the next, which is what the question is about, would be simpler. Your call though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own `SparseArray` types that has all the Array methods, but maintains a separate list of indices to iterate so that you can skip over holes efficiently.

Here's the start of such a type. It lets you iterate, push, add at specific indices, get/check specific indices.

There's also a `.toString()` that I added for display.

Not fully tested so there may be bugs. You'd need to add functionality as needed.

```js
function SparseArray(arr) {
  this.data = arr || [];
  this.indices = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      this.indices.push(i);        
    }
  }
}

SparseArray.prototype.forEach = function(cb, thisArg) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.indices.length; i++) {
    cb.call(thisArg, this.data[this.indices[i]], i, this);
  }
};

SparseArray.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.indices.push(this.data.push(item) - 1);
};

SparseArray.prototype.addAt = function(idx, item) {
  if (idx >= this.data.length) {
    this.indices.push(idx);
    
  } else if (!(idx in this.data)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.indices.length; i++) {
      if (this.indices[i] >= idx) {
        this.indices.splice(i, 0, idx);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  this.data[idx] = item;
};

SparseArray.prototype.hasIndex = function(idx) {
  return idx in this.data;
};

SparseArray.prototype.getIndex = function(idx) {
  return this.data[idx];
};

SparseArray.prototype.nextFrom = function(idx) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.indices.length; i++) {
    if (this.indices[i] >= idx) {
      return this.data[this.indices[i]];
    }
  }
};

SparseArray.prototype.toString = function() {
  var res = [];
  this.forEach(function(item) {
    res.push(item);
  });
  return res.join(", ");
};

var foo = [];
foo[0] = '0';
foo[1] = '1';
foo[2] = '2';
foo[100] = '100';

var pre = document.querySelector("pre");

var sa = new SparseArray(foo);

pre.textContent += "Start\n" + sa + "\n\n";

sa.addAt(1000, "1000");

pre.textContent += "Adding 1000\n" + sa + "\n\n";

sa.push("1001");

pre.textContent += "Pushing 1001\n" + sa + "\n\n";

pre.textContent += "Next from 300 is: " + sa.nextFrom(300) + "\n\n";
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

As squint mentioned in a comment above, one way I would do it involves another array. You could keep track of the indexes that actually mean something to you, that way you could jump straight to those indexes. I do however, have another idea.

If you want to eliminate large overhead, you could keep one array of values you care about, and one array of the indexes they correspond to. (Note that this is more like a Map - a datastructure in Java). That way, you can iterate over the numbers you need, and get the index you want in the other array.

```
Array 1: 1, 3, 6, 8
Array 2: 234, 298, 400, 500
```

So the value 1 occurs at index 234 in the data, the value 3 at 298...

I think this would greatly improve performance for large data sets and small data sets. However, I'm not totally sure how lookup works in javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `.slice()` , `.filter()`

```
// slice index of `curElement` + 1 through `foo` `.length`
var curr = foo.slice(foo.indexOf(curElement) + 1, foo.length);
// if `val` defined , return `val`
// alternatively , `return val !== undefined || val !== null`
var next = curr.filter(function(val) { return val })[0];
```

```js
var foo = [];
foo[0] = '0';
foo[1] = '1';
foo[2] = '2';
foo[100] = '100';
var curElement = foo[2]; // => 2 (the contents of foo[2])
var curr = foo.slice(foo.indexOf(curElement) + 1, foo.length);
var next = curr.filter(function(val) { return val})[0];
console.log(next)
```

---

Alternatively, could use `while` loop

```js
var foo = [];
foo[0] = '0';
foo[1] = '1';
foo[2] = '2';
foo[100] = '100';
var n = 2, next;
var curElement = foo[n]; // => 2 (the contents of foo[2])
while (n < foo.length) {
  if (foo[++n] !== undefined) {next = foo[n]; break;}
}
console.log(next)
```

Comment: As OP seems to be concerned with performance, this is not a good idea.

Comment: @LJᛃ This seems like a relatively in place solution, how is this poor in performance?

Comment: `slice` constructs a new array and reindexes the source array, using `filter` is way slower than manually iterating the values and also constructs a new array. In addition to that the proposed solution will also skip values that are `0`...

Comment: @LJᛃ Oh I see, so it's creating new objects behind the scenes too, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @NickZuber Simplest approach would be to use a `while` loop. Was not certain that requirement of Question excluded use of `.slice()` or `.filter()` ?  See at Question _"However, is there an explicit way to simply get from one of these elements to the next?"_ ? What is requirement ?

Comment: @guest271314 Well I'd like for the solution to be as efficient as possible, so while there's nothing against the use of `slice` and `filter` if they greatly reduce performance then a solution avoiding them would be better. Also, your solution apparently fails in a case where array values are `0` (which is why I believe somebody downvoted your answer - it wasn't me)

Comment: yeah I downvoted, because of the reasons stated in my comments above.

Comment: @NickZuber Try using `while` loop , see updated post. Note, condition at `if` could be adjusted to return expected results

Comment: correction: `slice` does **not** reindex the source array. Other points still remain valid though.

Comment: @LJᛃ Could alternatively use `while` loop, see updated post. What is benchmark for performance to return expected results ?